# numpy get rows where value in list within column

Tags: python, numpy

I have kind of an odd numpy ndarray, it looks like this:

```
[[0,1,3,list([0,1])],
[0,0,0,list([0])],
[0,0,0,list([])],
[1,1,1,list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])]]
```

so, the column at index 3 is actually of type `list`.

I would like to extract the rows which contain a key value in the list contained in index 3, so for instance, something like `magic_function(matrix, 0)` might return `[[0,1,3,list([0,1])], [0,0,0,list([0])]]`, as the rows at index 0 and 1 contain the value `0` in the list at index 3.

I tried using a combination of `np.where` and `np.isin`, but couldn't quite get it working in a way that was elegant (things like `matrix[np.where(np.isin(matrix[:,3], 0))]`). I would prefer the fastest approach, which I beleive would be an approach using numpy rather than iteration in python.

Comment: `[row for row in array if 0 in row[3]]`?

Comment: I would prefer to use built in numpy functions for speed, iteration in vanilla python is pretty slow (as I understand).

Comment: Since you are using variable size list inside your numpy, I think you cannot beat loop (unless you want to convert your lists into numpy)

Comment: Gotcha. Thinking about it I'm now suspecting as much. I guess a response including how to do this with numpy lists would work for those who are interested in creating a solution. Otherwise, I suppose `[row for row in array if 0 in row[3]]` is sufficient.

Comment: you can also do `arr[[0 in x for x in arr[:,3]]]` here arr is your array